# Calculating the probability of a function being real when it has random variables

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the probability of

$ax^2+bx+c$ root being a real number when the variables $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ values are all randomized by throwing a standard die.

I got to the point where I can get the probability by calculating the chance of $b^2-4ac>0$, but I'm not sure how I can conveniently carry on from here and my attempts at doing it by hand (finding every possible real occurrence and calculating them by the total outcomes) have failed me.

In other words, the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are within $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and each of the three variables is randomly picked from that list with no special weighting (so $\frac 16$  chance to get any of the $6$ values).

Comment: Rather than $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}>0$, you have ${b^2-4ac}>0$.

Comment: The computation depends on what you mean by 'randomized by throwing a standard dice'.

Comment: I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: When you edit, please note that "dice" is plural...the singular is "die".  If you meant a pair of dice (or more than $2$) you should say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $43$ triples $(a,b,c)$ with $b^2 - 4 a c \ge 0$,  so the probability is $43/6^3$.  Note that you do want $\ge$, not just $>$, unless you just want two distinct roots.
The easiest way to compute these by hand, I think, is to consider the possible values of $ac$.

Comment: Is the only legitimate way to really do it by hand?

Comment: @Grak : Probably there are some slick ways to do it, but maybe some of them won't be easy to find.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.

Comment: Well, the actual formula is $\sum_{b=1}^6 \sum_{a=1}^{\min(6,[\frac {b^2}{4}])} (c=[\frac {b^2}{4a}])$ but... well, the only good way to do that for me was by hand.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's legitimate to do it by computer?  As far as I'm concerned, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

We need $b^2 - 4ac \ge 0$.

If $b= 6$ then $ac \le 9$.  If $a =1$ then $c = 1...6$.  If $a=2$ then $c=1...4$.  If $c=3; a= 1..3$ if $a=4; c=1,2$ if $a=5,6;c =1$.  There are $6+4+3+2+1+1 = 17$ ways to do this.

If $b = 5$ then $ac \le 6$.  If $a=1$ then $c = 1...6$ if $a= 2$ then $b=1..3$ and if $a = 3; c=1,2$ and if $a \ge 4; c=1$.  So $6+3+2+3 = 14$ ways to do this.

If $b = 4$ then $ac \le 4$  So if $a= 1,2,3,4$ then $c \le 4,2,1,1$ so there are $4+2+1+1 = 8$ ways to do that

If $b =3$ then $ac \le 2$ So if $a= 1,2$ then $c \le 2,1$ so there are $2+1=3$ wways to do that.

If $b = 2$ then $ac \le 1$ so $a=c=1$.  $1$ way to do that.

$b$ can not be $1$ because $4ac \ge 4 > 1^2$.

So there are $17+14+8+3+1 = 43$ ways to do this.

So the probability is $\frac {43}{6^3} \approx 20\%$ (very slightly less.)